# Cant print list out of python function

Tags: python, list

Not that great at python so I might be making a mistake, but my SplitAgain only prints the first line outside of the function. I did try having a forloop but that didnt work either.

```
print 'List Local Files'
localFile = open('Local.csv','r')

for line in localFile:
    splitLine = line.split(",")
    splitAgain = splitLine[9].replace('"', '')

   # print splitAgain


print 'Collection Files'
CollectionFile = open('Collection.csv', 'r')
for line in CollectionFile:
       sLine = line.split(",")

       newArray = sLine[4] + sLine[5]


       newArray2 = newArray.replace("/XXXX/",'')



print splitAgain
```

I would want splitAgain to print all the values outside of the foorloop, as i will be running a diff on SplitAgain and newArray2 in the second stage.

But at this stage it only gives me the first line.

I did try iteration of the list, but it gave me each character on a new line.

I tried this

```
  for i in SplitAgain:
    print i;
```

Comment: What function? I don't see a function.

Comment: meant out of the loop, sorry

Comment: Have you tried storing the results of each iteration?

Comment: yeah i did, the iteration just gave me each letter on new line

Comment: the problem is that you don't store splitAgain anywhere. Its common to have a list, maybe splitAgain_list, and `splitAgain_list.append(splitAgain)` in the for loop. Maybe you'll figure out better ways to express what you want, but its a start.

Comment: Give an example with input and output, because your question isn't clear enough to understand what you really want!

Comment: Don't put answers in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to get the value for a column in a csv file and print it. Here a modified version of your code.

```
print 'List Local Files'

VALUES_SEPARATOR = ","

with open('./local.csv','r') as localFile :
    lines = []
    for line in localFile:
        #use line[:-1] to remove the end line "\n" symbol.
        splitLine = line[:-1].split(VALUES_SEPARATOR)
        splitAgain = splitLine[2].replace('"', '')

        lines.append(splitAgain)#store the line in a out-of-the-loop variable.

    print(lines)
```

As you can see a list is used to store the result outside of the loop as @tdelaney suggested it in comments. Applyied on this file :

```
name, owner,"local file names"
foo,bar,"foo the foo"
foofoo,bar,"bar the bar"
```

It give the following result :

```
List Local Files
['local file names', 'foo the foo', 'bar the bar']
```

Is that satisfying your needs ?
I hope so ;)

Comment: thanks for the help, i was just unsure why my variable(list, splitAgain) wasnt printing all the values outside of loop. 

It turned out I needed a array value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try making **splitAgain** as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be like:

```
print ('List Local Files')
localFile = open('Local.csv','r')

for line in localFile:
    splitLine = line.split(",")
    splitAgain = splitLine[9].replace('"', '')

   # print (splitAgain)


print ('Collection Files')
CollectionFile = open('Collection.csv', 'r')
for line in CollectionFile:
       sLine = line.split(",")

       newArray = sLine[4] + sLine[5]


       newArray2 = newArray.replace("/XXXX/",'')



print (splitAgain)
```

This is python so no need for ;.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! At this 8 year old post already was an accepted and upvoted answer, so probably this answer was quite useful to the author. It would be great if you use your skills to answer actual and/or unanswered questions. Thanks for contributing to this site!